# JSON decoding error when querying Wikidata

Tags: python, encoding, wikidata

I get a decoding error trying to decode my json data obtained from wikidata. I've read it may be because I'm trying to decode bytes instead of UTF-8 but I've tried to decode into UTF-8 and I can't seem to find the way to do so... Here's my method code (the parameter is a string and the return a boolean):

```
def es_enfermedad(candidato):
    url = 'https://query.wikidata.org/sparql'
    query = """
            SELECT ?item WHERE {
              ?item rdfs:label ?nombre.
              ?item wdt:P31 ?tipo.
              VALUES ?tipo {wd:Q12135}
              FILTER(LCASE(?nombre) = "%s"@en)
            }
            """ % (candidato)
    r = requests.get(url, params = {'format': 'json', 'query': query})
    data = r.json()
    return len(data['results']['bindings']) > 0
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: I get this exception:  
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: What is the value of `candidato`? And if you print out `r.text` – do you get a `404 - Not Found`?

Comment: Please show an example of what the API returns

Comment: Tries to print the value of `r`, it is probably not a json, and `https://query.wikidata.org/w/api.php` seems to be broken

Comment: I'm now using https://query.wikidata.org/sparql as the url. When I print r.text it gives me an html with title "Wikimedia Error".

Comment: I query elastic search to find significant terms and iterate the list and pass those strings as parameter for this method